# internal error in photoshop elements automation

Tags: c#, photoshop

```
public static Photoshop.Application appRef = default(Photoshop.Application);  
appRef = new ApplicationClass();
appRef.Visible = false;
appRef.DisplayDialogs = PsDialogModes.psDisplayNoDialogs;
```

Internal error appear on appRef.visible=false line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "internal error" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)